# Spring Data with Scala

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, scala

As been asked before, it is not recommended to use Spring Data or Hibernate on Scala because it doesn't work well with it's byte code manipulation (and some interface incompatibilities).

---

My question is however, because it is possible to code Scala and Java in parallel with SBT, is it a good idea to code my repositories and services in Java and then use them in my Scala code? Does this get rid of the byte code constraint?

I'm asking here because I couldn't find any resources on this.

Answer (score 2):

There are no issues using Scala for Hibernate.  You don't even need to use `@BeanProperty`.  For example:

```
@Entity
class Role {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  var id: Long = _

  @Index(name="role_name")
  var name: String = _

  var created_at: Date = _
  var updated_at: Date = _  

  @ManyToMany
  private var sub_role: java.util.Set[Role] = _
  def subRoles: Set[Role] = {
    if (sub_role == null) sub_role = new java.util.HashSet[Role]
    sub_role
  }

  @ManyToMany
  private var permission: java.util.Set[Permission] = _
  def permissions: Set[Permission] = {
    if (permission == null) permission = new java.util.HashSet[Permission]
    permission
  }
}
```

This is an example class from one of a number of Scala/Hibernate projects I've worked on.

One thing that you do need to use Java for is custom JSR-303 validation annotations.

Comment: Hi @sourcedelica, do you have more examples? I gave up to use scala ORM and want to go back to JPA. I consider spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

It's possible; you can also achieve the same thing by just being aware of how e.g. Hibernate wants to interface with classes and writing scala classes in the same format (lots of `@BeanProperty var x: String = _`). But you'll find that such classes (whether written in Java or Scala) are not very idiomatic for use from scala; there'll be friction when trying to use them with Scala libraries (which are better adapted for use with immutable case classes rather than java beans). So you can write systems using this approach, at least for a transitional period, but ultimately you're better off choosing just one of scala or java, and using a library that's idiomatic for your preferred language.